Minimum value of $|z^4+z+\frac{1}{2}|$ on the unit circle
Let $z$ be a complex number. What is the minimum value of the expression  $|z^4+z+\frac{1}{2}|$ for $|z|=1$?
I wanted to explore the long process of considering $z=x+iy$, and substituting to get the following expression:
$$W = \left|(x+iy)^4+x+iy+\frac{1}{2}\right|^2=\left|x^4 + 4 i x^3 y - 6 x^2 y^2 - 4 i x y^3 + y^4+x+iy+\frac{1}{2}\right|^2$$
$$W(x,y)=x^8+4x^6y^2+2x^5+6x^4y^4+x^4-4x^3y^2+4x^2y^6-6x^2y^2+x^2-6xy^4+x+y^8+y^4+y^2+\frac{1}{4}$$
Also, $$x^2+y^2=1$$
I am interested to learn the list of methods can I use to minimize this above expression.

Note : I have got the answer using the substitution of $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ to get the minimum value of $W$ as $\frac{1}{8}$


If you want to restrict to finding a solution using $z=x+iy$, Lagrangian multipliers are probably the simplest method. Are you familiar with that technique? (As you point out, though, the most natural way to answer the question is the substitution $z=e^{i\theta}$)

Actually, you can get pretty far with just algebraic manipulations.
Starting from
$$W=x^8+4x^6y^2+2x^5+6x^4y^4+x^4-4x^3y^2+4x^2y^6-6x^2y^2+x^2-6xy^4+x+y^8+y^4+y^2+\frac{1}{4}$$
we see the highest degree terms are $x^8+y^8$ which suggests adding
$0=1-\left(x^2+y^2\right)^4$ to both sides; this results in
$$W=2 x^5 + x^4 - 4 x^3 y^2 - 6 x^2 y^2 + x^2 - 6 x y^4 + x + y^4 + y^2 + \frac54$$
Similarly, we can add $0=2-\left(x^2+y^2\right)-\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2$ to both sides to give
$$W=2 x^5 - 4 x^3 y^2 - 8 x^2 y^2 - 6 x y^4 + x + \frac{13}{4}$$
Now using $2x\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2=2x$,
$$W=-8 x^3 y^2 - 8 x^2 y^2 - 8 x y^4 + 3 x + \frac{13}{4}$$
We can rewrite this as
$$W=-8 xy^2\left(x^2+x+y^2\right)+ 3 x + \frac{13}{4}=-8 xy^2\left(1+x\right)+ 3 x + \frac{13}{4}$$
Finally, substituting $y^2=1-x^2$ gives
$$W=8 x^4 + 8 x^3 - 8 x^2 - 5 x + 13/4$$
Treating $W$ as a function of $x$ and differentiating,
$$W'=32x^3+24x^2-16x-5=(4x+1)\left(8x^2+4x-5\right)$$
and it's fairly simple from here to show the minimum $W=\frac18$ is achieved at $x=\frac14\pm\frac{\sqrt{11}}{4}$.

thank you very much

You introduce $W = |z^4+z+\frac{1}{2}|^2$.  I recommend using complex conjugates $z^*$ which gives, since $x^2+y^2=1$, the formulation $z z^* = 1$ and  $z = e^{j \phi}$, so you have
$$
W = |z^4+z+\frac{1}{2}|^2 = (z^4+z+\frac{1}{2})({z^*}^4+{z^*}+\frac{1}{2})\\
= 1 + 1 + \frac14 + 2 \mathrm{Re} \, [z {z^*}^4 + \frac{z^4+z}{2} ]\\
= \frac94 +  \mathrm{Re} \, [2 e^{j 3 \phi} + e^{j 4 \phi} + e^{j \phi}]\\
=  \frac94 +  2 \cos{3 \phi} + \cos{ 4 \phi} + \cos{ \phi}
$$.
Using trigonometric  equalities for multiples of entries, let $\cos \phi = x = \mathrm{Re} \, z$ and you have
$$
W = 
 \frac94 +  8 x^4 + 8x^3 - 8x^2 - 5x + 1 \\
= \frac{125}{32} + 8 (x+\frac14)^4 - 11(x+\frac14)^2  
$$
where inspiration for the symmetry to $-\frac14$ was found by plotting the function.
This biquadratic equation can easily be solved, it has a global minimum at $(x+\frac14)^2 = \frac{11}{16}$, so the minimum is attained for $-1 \le x \le 1$,  at
$$
 x = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{11}}{4} \simeq 0.58
$$
and indeed then you have $W =  8 (11/16)^2 - 11(11/16)  +125/32 = \frac18$ at $z \simeq 0.58 \pm i 0.65$.

Is this different from just substituting $z=\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$, though? (Which I thought we wanted to avoid)

@ChrisLewis Yes, we want $z=\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$ ultimately. The point is: at which point in the process of manipulations do we introduce it? The method of complex conjugates avoids terms in $x$ AND $y$, it also avoids the powers $x^8 + y^8$ etc. which then need to be handled by appropriate extensions of the polynomial.  The expression comes in terms of $x$ (only) to 4th order right away. Only AFTER solving for $x$ we reintroduce $z=\cos\phi+i\sin\phi = x + i \sqrt{1-x^2}$ .

Thank you for the answer, however this primarily what i did to solve the question and avoid the $x^8$ and such higher degree terms, as mentioned in the question, my question was how to deal with such higher degree multivariable polynomials

You may first simplify the expression:
$$|z^4 + z + 1/2| = |z^4 + z + 1/2| \cdot |\bar{z}^2|
= |z^2 + \bar{z} + \bar{z}^2/2|.$$
Let $z = x + \mathrm{i} y$ with $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.
We have
$$z^2 + \bar{z} + \bar{z}^2/2
= (x^2 - y^2 + \mathrm{i} 2xy) + (x - \mathrm{i} y) + 
(x^2 - y^2 - \mathrm{i} 2xy)/2$$
$$= 3(x^2 - y^2)/2 + x + \mathrm{i}(x - 1)y.$$
We have
$$|z^4 + z + 1/2|^2 = |z^2 + \bar{z} + \bar{z}^2/2|^2
= (3(x^2 - y^2)/2 + x)^2 + (x-1)^2y^2$$
$$ = (3x^2 - 3/2 + x)^2 + (x-1)^2(1-x^2) $$
where we use $y^2 = 1 - x^2$.
We need to find the minimum of
$$f(x) := (3x^2 - 3/2 + x)^2 + (x-1)^2(1-x^2)
= 8x^4 + 8x^3 - 8x^2 - 5x + 13/4$$
subject to $-1 \le x \le 1$.
I would like to eliminate the term of degree three by introducing $x = y + a$ for some $a$. We find $a = -1/4$ to obtain
$$f = 8y^4 - 11y^2 + \frac{125}{32}
= 8(y^2 - 11/16)^2 + 1/8.$$
This is a lucky thing (because it eliminates both the terms of degree three and degree one).
Thus, we have $f\ge 1/8$ with equality if e.g. $y = \frac14\sqrt{11}$ and $x = y - 1/4 = \frac14\sqrt{11} -1/4$.

Thank you this helped
